# How to import a javascript file in node package?

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is a js file 'hello.js' in 'myPackage' in node_modules

This is my hello.js

```
console.log('hello');
```

And in my project, i want to use import that hello.js

If my main.js is

```
//some syntax that import hello.js    
console.log('hello2');
```

My goal is

```
hello
hello2
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

require() resolves Paths without "./" or "/" prefix to node_modules:

```
//some syntax that import hello.js
let exportOfHelloJSIfYouWishToCatchIt = require("myPackage/hello");
console.log('hello2');
```

should work just great.

Answer (score 0):

You require the file (you have to specify the path).

your main.js should be like:

```
require("./node_modules/myPackage/hello.js");
console.log("hello2");
```

and your hello.js is like:

```
console.log("hello");
```

when you run :

```
node main.js
```

hello

hello2

Comment: But, the hello.js file is in 'myPackage' which is a node module in 'node_module' directory

Comment: ye , you are right I edited, anyway you can "import" a file just using require so giving the path to the module should work

Answer (score 0):

You could rename `node_modules/myPackage/hello.js` to `node_modules/myPackage/index.js` and make use one of the default values for package main property (otherwise you'd have to write a package.json, but that's not a bad idea either.)

Then you'd be able to `require()` your module like this:

main.js

```
require('myPackage');
console.log('hello2');
```

Your whole module code is executed while requiring it so it'd print to console as expected.

Comment: Renaming isn't required: `require('myPackage/hello.js')`.